# Installing Nginx server

Tags: nginx, makefile, tar, configure

I am trying to install Nginx server on ubuntu using

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.5.3
./configure
make
install
```

this is what I get:

```
 tar: Skipping to next header

 gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error

 gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error 
 tar: Child returned status 1
 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
 ./configure: 10: .: Can't open auto/options
 make:  *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
 make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

What seems to be the problem with all these errors?

Comment: Do you really need to install it from the sources? Any particular reason not to use the repositories?

Comment: i want to write a script for this installation that's why i want to install it from resources

Comment: you download nginx-1.0.5.tar.gz, but uncompress nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz

Comment: just a typing mistake, corrected

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a bunch of tar errors, which might mean that the archive is broken. Try to address those issues first before doing a make.
I would start with  replacing `tar xvfz nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz`
with `tar -xvzf nginx-1.5.3.tar.gz`

Comment: I am aware of the tar problem, in fact it is the source for configure and make problems, i tried this but same error

Answer (score 0):

is gzip installed already? check by:

```
whereis gzip
```

and install it on ubuntu by:

```
sudo apt-get install gzip
```